# RabbitMQ: change port on Windows Server

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed and programmed against RabbitMQ server locally, and now it is time to move to our development Windows machine.

I have the following default listening ports:

[image]

I cannot connect from my local code to the RabbitMQ on the Windows server: it gives a connection exception.
So: I guess I need to add  and port 5672 also in the list above.

But, something trivial as adding this: I could not make it work.

When I go to the etc folder, there is a rabbitmq.config.example but also a read me file saying:

> In this directory you can find an example configuration file for RabbitMQ.
>
> Note that this directory is *not* where the real RabbitMQ
>   configuration lives. The default location for the real configuration
>   file is %APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.config.
>
> %APPDATA% usually expands to C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming or similar.

So, I go to that directory and I add the rabbitmq.config file and modify the following lines:

```
    {tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 5672},
                 {"192.168.x.xx", 5672},
                 {"::1",       5672}]},
```

I guess I need to restart the server now, but it says:

> ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "dev_test_server"

Nothing has changed in the list of the listening ports.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, before everything else, I would advise you to reconfigure rabbit to not to use `%appdata%`; it will give you problems later on since it's loaded in a user profile.

Comment: If you are going to ask that as a question, I have got an `how to` ready to post.

Comment: @Stefan Here is the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383539/how-to-reconfigure-rabbitmq-not-to-use-appdata

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer. It might resolve this issue as well.

Comment: It didn't resolve this issue. Still no extra line added.

Comment: Ok, nevertheless, since you re-targeted the directory, you don't get into the user-access-rights-hell later on. Let me read your question again.

Comment: A couple of things you might want to check: 1) you cannot use the guest account to connect to non-localhost. 2) restarting the service is best performed through the bat files in the `sbin` directory (for some reason)

Comment: All already checked.

Comment: I think you can remove the extra line, I'll check my own configuration. But what is the initial connection exception? Isn't it a simple firewall issue?

Comment: My own config just looks like this: `{tcp_listeners, [5672]}`

Comment: Even if I change that port to 8513, nothing changes in the web admin. Still listing 5672 as listening port. Changed the config files, stop + start service via command line.

Comment: Interesting... I am running out of options. It seems that the configuration is not loaded correctly. That reminds me, rabbit has altered their config file construction recently, are you aware of that? see: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

Comment: Yes, I have also set RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT but it doesn't move.

Comment: How are you restarting the service? It must be something simple which we arn't seeing.

Comment: Remove => install => start service

Comment: I guess that should be enough XD.... I am blank :/ ... although: In the managmentplugin (http, see other question), you can see the path of the used config file. Can you verify you are editting the correct one?

Comment: It is the correct one.