# How to reconfigure RabbitMQ not to use %appdata% on Windows?

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

How to reconfigure RabbitMQ not to use %appdata% for config files?

Follow up for question [RabbitMQ: change port on Windows Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383334/rabbitmq-change-port-on-windows-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as described, a how to on how to re-config rabbit MQ to use an arbitrary directory. This will have some benefits regarding access of the database files etc. when running as a service without having to redefine the `%appdata%` access rights, which are user bound.

In your windows environmental settings, you'll need to redefine `RABBITMQ_BASE`, I have tested it with `c:\rmq` ([or one of the others as described in the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html)). Set it to the directory you want to target. See image:

[image]

Next, it seems you need to run some commands, I haven't been able to target the correct directory during or prior installation.

So, run the following commands, basically it reinstalls the service again:

> C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.14\sbin>rabbitmq-service.bat remove
>
> C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.14\sbin>rabbitmq-service.bat install
>
> C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.14\sbin>rabbitmq-service.bat start

Optional: reinstall management plugin:

> C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.14\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

As you can see, the database files are placed in the `c:\rmq` directory.

[image]